# date-fns subDays - How to get 00:00 time insted of 12:17:35

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

I am trying to change moment for date-fns

```
    moment: moment().startOf('day').subtract(1, 'day').toDate(),
    date-fns: subDays(new Date(), 1),
```

Moment give me back this:
Moment: Thu Jun 10 2021 **00:00:00** GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)

and date-fns this:
Datefn: Thu Jun 10 2021 **12:17:35** GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)

I am wondering if is it any way to get the same time on date-fns. This **00:00:00** instead of this **12:17:35**

Comment: Have you tried using `startOfToday()` instead of `new Date()`?

Comment: No, I haven't but I will, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this it should work.

```
date-fns: startOfDay(subDays(new Date(), 1))
```